# How to ignore the error message "cannot find pdb files"?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, pdb-files

I am asking this question because obviously I have searched the internet and whenever some guy puts up a question about the missing dll files the most common answer is "to ignore it" because its not an error but a warning. Well I want to know how to do that, because I see no such option and the code doesn't run.

I have tried for loading the symbols from the Microsoft symbol server. Well that worked for me in many cases but unfortunately not in the case of "'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file." (coz nvedia symbols has not much to do with microsoft servers)and after this error the application/code exits without even starting. Also it didn't work for "nvinit.dll". I have some idea what a pdb file is.also i have tried changing my code to release mode and  changed the properties accordingly by changing the incremental linkage to "no" and debug info to "no" and all that so that i may not have to use the pdb files  but nothing helped......my code is still not running.so the only option is to ignore the error.. or warning as i must say,which i am unable to..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel you. I'm doing PlayStation development, and they have special debuggers and toolchains and the whole nine yards, but the debugger has taken to complaining that it can't find a file "libkernel.pdb", which is legitimate because it doesn't exist, but it never has, I don't understand why things when south on me all of a sudden. I'm depressed that you made this comment in '13 and I left this note in '20. Not a good sign.

Comment: I do have one suggestion - something I'm going to try. The missing file is detected very early in initialization, well before main, and it manifests as an exception, and exceptions can be ignored. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Too ignore something, literally just "ignore it" don't worry about it, unless you have some particular reason for wanting to get rid of them, they wont affect you at all.

Comment: Please read  the description carefully ...i have written "the code doesn't run "....so i have every reason in the world to get rid of these warnings